# Get max value for identity column without a table scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with an Identity column `Id`.

When I execute:

```
 select max(Id) from Table
```

SQL Server does a table scan and stream aggregate.

My question is, why can it not simply look up the last value assigned to Id? It's an `identity`, so the information must be tracked, right?

Can I look this up manually?

Comment: Is the `Id` also the clustered index?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) to look up the last identity value to be inserted, e.g.

```
IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable')
```

However, be cautious when using this function. A failed transaction can still increment this value, and, as `Quassnoi` states, this row might have been deleted.

It's likely that it does a table scan because it can't guarantee that the last identity value is the MAX value. For example the identity might not be a simple incrementing integer. You could be using a decrementing integer as your identity.

Answer (score 5):

What if you have deleted the latest record?

The value of `IDENTITY` would not correspond to the actual data anymore.

If you want fast lookups for `MAX(id)`, you should create an index on it (or probably declare it a `PRIMARY KEY`)

Comment: @Blorgbeard: sure, I believe you, it's `SQL Server` that does not.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. Lots of good reasons in this thread that I should forget the whole thing and stick with Max(Id) :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard, you do use up an identity every time an insert fails not just when you delete.

Answer (score 2):

Is the table clustered on that column?
Can you use Top 1:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [ID]     
FROM [Table]
order by ID desc
```

Comment: It's not clustered on Id. I did try this, but it does a scan/sort which is slower than Max(ID).

Answer (score 1):

You can run this following statement and remove the last `UNION ALL`. Run this statement to get the current Identity values.

```
SELECT 
  ' SELECT '+char(39)+[name]+char(39)+' AS table_name, IDENT_CURRENT('+char(39)+[name]+char(39)+') AS currvalue UNION ALL'
  AS currentIdentity
FROM sys.all_objects WHERE type = 'U'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Id the primary key or indexed?  Seems like it should do a seek in those cases.

Comment: No, there's no index on it and it's not the PK

Comment: @Blorgbeard Since IDENT_CURRENT() may not reflect the data in your table it cannot be used for MAX() and you have no indexes, so you end up with a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could set up an index on that field in descending order and it would use that to find the largest key. It should be fast.

Comment: Would work, but I am not allowed to add an index to this DB just for this